# Was Amos 6 insured for pre-launch operations?

Tags: launch, spacex, falcon-9, testing, insurance

The Falcon 9 rocket, complete with the Amos 6 payload, just blew up (Or RUDed) on [the launch pad](http://arstechnica.com/science/2016/09/spacexs-falcon-9-rocket-apparently-blew-up-during-a-test-firing-thursday/). I believe the standard language for most launch insurances is that it is only covered after "Intentional launch" of the vehicle, specifically limiting incidences like that which occurred this morning. Was Amos 6 insured, and how are such issues typically managed?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Rewriting with clarification, I apparently misinterpreted the second tweet. Source still is [this twitter feed](https://twitter.com/pbdes) (from a [spacenews.com](http://www.spacenews.com) reporter).

The launch insurance doesn't count:

> SpaceX explosion didnt involve intentional ignition - E Musk said occurred during 2d stage fueling - & isn't covered by launch insurance. [(tweet)](https://twitter.com/pbdes/status/771409425475174400)

However, the satellite was insured under a different policy until launch:

> Spacecom insured Amos-6 for $285M in marine cargo market, not space insurance market. Launch +1 yr policy would kick in at rocket ignition. [(tweet)](https://twitter.com/pbdes/status/771409983074426881)
>
> @cbs_spacenews Sat was insured as marine cargo for pre-launch phase. Launch policy didn't kick in because no ignition-w/-intent-to-launch. [(tweet)](https://twitter.com/pbdes/status/771410879770456064)

Verdict appears to be that the satellite was insured (and that reporting with clarity via twitter is hard, the repeated focus on launch insurance is misleading).

Comment: Why do they "test" the first stage with the payload onboard?? It kind of doubles the risk of losing the payload at launch, since it has to endure two launch attempts. Why would anyone want to insure such a thing?

Comment: @LocalFluff That's another question entirely. As for why they insure it, it's because there is so rarely a problem with pre-launch operations.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto If it is so rare, why do they test for it? How does putting the payload at stake during a "test" launch lower the insurance premium? If I were the insurer, I'd instead rather double it for the payload.

Comment: Catastrophic issues are rare. Non-catastrophic issues are common. I think almost every static fire test for Falcon 9 of the first 5-6 revealed something wrong, that had to be addressed prior to launch. The payload is insured through their own policy prior to launch, I doubt the rocket has such a policy.

Comment: @LocalFluff see http://space.stackexchange.com/q/18020/4660

Comment: An interesting aside for this type of insurance arrangement, with one insurer covering to a moment before ignition and the other from that point onwards, is that if a problem were to be discovered with the satellite in orbit and if it was shown that it likely related to engine induced vibration, then it might be difficult to determine which insurer should pay.